# How to convert XMLSS(XML SpreadSheet) into a byte array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, arrays

I was wondering if we can convert into a byte array an XML spreadsheet the same way as a normal XML file in c#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any file into a byte array.
Get a handle on the file and turn it into a stream.  From there you are just reading the file into a byte array.  Although this isn't exactly what you are doing, it gives an example on how to convert the file into a byte array:

`Dim fs As Stream = fupDocLibrary.PostedFile.InputStream

 Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)

Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)`

Here I am using a file upload control, but it should be just as easy to read a file from the directory and convert it the same way.